# Need to retrive values from Session object using foreach in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have mvc 3 application in which in session object i'm taking all values that is needed to me as parameter to execute stored procedure.

If the userAction is update then execute stored procedure.

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction) 
{ 
   if(Session["Mappings"] != null)            
        ViewData["Message"] = "Mapping web grid"; 

    if (Session["PricingSecurities"] == null) 
        Session["PricingSecurities"] = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID(); 
    if (Session["Cusips"] == null) 
        Session["Cusips"] = objRepository.GetCUSIP(); 

    SecurityMappingModel objModel = null; 
    mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"]; 

    objModel = new SecurityMappingModel(); 


    if (userAction == "Update" ) 
    { 
        //help me to fix this code 

        //foreach (var item in Session)
        //{Session["Mappings"] //NEED FIX HERE
        //}
        // PLEASE HELP ME TO RETRIEVE SESSION VALUES
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    } 
    return View(objModel); 
}
```

HOW CAN I RETRIEVE ALL VALUES OF Session["Mappings"] it is holding 3entries 3ids,3cusips,3calculation

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to not use `var` as your enumeration type, use `object` instead.

```
foreach (obj item in Session) {
    if (item is CUSIP) {
        // CUSIP processing
    } else if (item is PricingSecurity) {
        //Pricing security processing
    } //etc.
}
```

As you can see, the problem with this approach is that you will have to test each object for it's type in order to perform any custom action on it. A better idea would be to create your own class to store in the session:

```
public class SessionData()
{
    List<CUSIP> Cusips {get;set;}
    List<PricingSecurity> PricingSecurities {get;set;}

    public SessionData()
    {
        // Initialize the lists so they are never null
        this.Cusips = new List<CUSIP>();
        this.PricingSecurities = new List<PricingSecurity>();
    }
}
```

Then you can just loop through each of the list properties and perform any actions you need.